# Remove non duplicated lines in text file

Tags: python, linux, sorting, sed, uniq

I have a long list 100k+ of IP addresses in a certain range, an example from this script is:

```
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.143.13 0
```

From this list I am wanting to remove any IP's that are not listed multiple times, so say I would like to remove all ips from the list above that aren't listed 5 or more times. It would then output:

```
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.232.158 0
```

I've tried to accomplish this using sed/uniq in Linux but wasn't able to find a way to do this, would a python script or such be needed for this or is there a possible way using sed/uniq?

Using sort -u 100kfile, it was able to remove all duplicates, but it was still left with the single ip's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sort`, `uniq` and `awk`:

```
pu@pumbair: ~  sort data.txt | uniq -c | awk '{if ($1 > 4) print $2,$3}'
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.123.150 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.232.158 0
```

Comment: Seems to miss a few if they are scattered out, I tried it on my big list and it appears to be duplicating some still http://puu.sh/bn8Kl/bc8b1d6bf7.txt

Comment: +1: You can do it entirely in `awk`. `awk ' { ips[$0]++ } END { for (ip in ips) if (ips[ip] >= 5) print ip }' data.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Pure Python solution, using the `Counter` tool from the [`collections` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

I have no idea how this will do with 100k addresses, but you could give it a go.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('ip_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    ip_list     = map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readlines())
    ip_by_count = Counter(ip_list)

    for ip in ip_by_count:
        if ip_by_count[ip] > 1:
            print ip
```

Or an alternative approach: maintain two sets, one of IPs seen exactly once, and one for IPs seen at least twice. Print an IP when we see it for a second time, and skip all subsequent appearances:

```
known_dupes = set()
single_ips  = set()

with open('ip_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    ip_list = map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readlines())

    for ip in ip_list:
        if ip in known_dupes:
            continue
        elif ip in single_ips:
            print ip
            known_dupes.add(ip)
            single_ips.remove(ip)
        else:
            single_ips.add(ip)
```

I suspect the first is probably faster, but I haven’t tried it on a large file to check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it in `awk`

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) if (a[i]>4) print i}' file
67.0.232.158 0
67.0.105.76 0
67.0.163.127 0
67.0.123.150 0
```

Count every unique IP and store the number in an array `a`
If there are more then `4` hit, print it.
It should be faster then the `sort` `uniq` `awk`

PS I did see after I posted this, its the same as jaypal posted in a comment.